# Comparar imagenes

Tags: android, array

estoy tratando de hacer una aplicación que toma una imagen al azar de un array y la muestra en un imagen view. Lo que quiero hacer ahora, y no puedo, es que según la imagen que aparezca quiero que pasen diferentes cosas, trate con un switch pero no funciona, ¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

Mi codigo:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button b1, b2,b3,b4,b5;
ImageView iv1,iv2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    iv1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv1);
    iv2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv2);
    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
    b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b2);
    b3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b3);
    b4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b4);
    b5=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b5);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void Accion1 (View view){

    final TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.RandomImages);
    final Random rand = new Random();
    final int rndInt = rand.nextInt(imgs.length());
    final int rID = imgs.getResourceId(rndInt, 0);
    iv2.setImageResource(rID);

    b1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    b2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

public void Accion2(View view){
    b2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    switch (iv2.getId()){
        case 1:
            iv2.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagen1);
            b3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        case 2:
            iv2.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagen2);
            b4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        case 3:
            iv2.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagen3);
            b5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: switch (iv2.getId()) que ID esperas aqui?

Comment: Esperaba obtener el nombre de la imagen que apareció, compararla y según cual sea que pase algo. Por ejemplo si la imagen que salio es azul que pase tal cosa, en cambio si salio la imagen roja que pase otra cosa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se me ocurre lo siguiente:

```
public void Accion1 (View view){

    final TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.RandomImages);
    final Random rand = new Random();
    final int rndInt = rand.nextInt(imgs.length());
    final int rID = imgs.getResourceId(rndInt, 0);
    iv2.setImageResource(rID);
    iv2.setTag(rID);

    b1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    b2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

public void Accion2(View view){
    b2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    int tagImageView = (int) iv2.getTag();
    switch (tagImageView){
        case R.drawable.imagenX:
            iv2.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagen1);
            b3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        case R.drawable.imagenY:
            iv2.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagen2);
            b4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        case R.drawable.imagenZ:
            iv2.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagen3);
            b5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes crear un TypedArray conteniendo los posibles ids

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#TypedArray

Por ejemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <array name="mis_imagenes">
        <item>@drawable/imagen1</item>
        <item>@drawable/imagen2</item>
        <item>@drawable/imagen3</item>
    </array>
</resources>
```

Obtienes los valores de esta forma:

```
Resources res = getResources();
TypedArray imagenes = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.mis_imagenes);
```

El drawable lo obtienes de esta forma:

```
Drawable drawable = imagenes.getDrawable("valor random 0 a 3 que es la cantidad de elementos definidos");
```